# How to check mellanox (mlnx) ethernet card firmware and driver version?

Tags: networking, drivers, firmware

AFAIK I think this is how I could check the firmware of a Mellanox Ethernet card:

```
SERVER:~ # for i in 0 1 2 3 ; do ethtool -i eth$i|grep -i firmware; done|sort -u|cut -d' ' -f 2-
14.23.1020 (LNV2420110034)
```

and this is how I could check the driver version:

```
SERVER:~ # modinfo mlx5_core|grep ^version:|sed 's/version: * //g'
4.3-1.0.1
SERVER:~ #
```

The question: is this true? Can someone confirm?

SLES12.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet gets the firmware versions of 4 network interfaces named `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2` and `eth3` whether or not they are Mellanox cards, removes duplicates and sorts the resulting version numbers in alphanumeric order. For getting the firmware version of one network interface whose name is known (e.g. `eth0`), this will be sufficient:

```
ethtool -i eth0 | grep -i firmware | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

The second snippet, assuming the driver name is always going to be `mlx5_core`, is correct.